# using document.forms["MbrForm"].submit(); does not work

Tags: javascript

I have a form that I need to have two means of submitting the form. The first way is with the standard submit button. This works just fine. The seond way is supposed to first print the page, then display an alert and finally submit the form. This second way is where I need the help.

For the second way I have a button in the form that calls the "printpage" function. This function prints the page, displays an alert and then is supposed to submit the form. It does everything except for submit the form. Any help figuring out why is appreciated.

The code for the htm page is shown below.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function printpage()
{
    if (MbrForm_Validator(document.forms["MbrForm"]))
    {
    window.print();
    alert("Thank you for your support of the Friends. Please mail your form and check to the address shown on the printed        page.");
//***********************************************************************************
//***********************************************************************************
//this is the line of code that does not work for me        
        document.forms["MbrForm"].submit();
//***********************************************************************************
//***********************************************************************************
    }
}

function MbrForm_Validator(theform)
{
//removed for brevity
}
</script>

        <h1>Membership Application</h1>
        <p style="margin:0px;text-size:9px;"><sup class="required">*</sup>Denotes required information</p>
        <form id="MbrForm" name="MbrForm" method="post" action="membertest.php" onsubmit="return MbrForm_Validator(this)" target="_blank">
```

the contents of the form itself have been removed for brevity. Only the SUBMIT and PRINT buttons remain

```
            <table width="75%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="5" class="displayonly">
                <caption style="border-bottom:black solid 1px;">
                    How Would You Like to Pay? 
                </caption>
                <tr>
                    <td width="49%" valign="top">
                        With a check<br />
                        Click the "Print" button below to print this form for mailing in with your check.
                    </td>
                    <td width="51%" valign="top">
                        On-Line with a Credit Card<br />
                        Click the "Submit" button below to submit your information and pay using a credit card or PayPal.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div align="left">
                            <input type="button" name="btnprint" id="btnprint" value="Print" onclick="printpage()" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="left">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
        <div class="printonly">
            <p>
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <hr />
                Mail with your check to:<br />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your forms "submit" handler calls that "MbrForm_Validator" function directly, but you didn't show that code!

Comment: the "MbrForm_Validator" dunction just validates the data enterd into the form - i.e. telephone number field contains a telephone number, zip field contains a zip code type number, etc, etc. It si the same "MbrForm_Validator" function that is called by the "printpage" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this problem, thanks in part to the several previous comments.

The solution is to make both buttons "Submit" type buttons with the same name.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="button" name="btnprint" id="btnprint" value="Print" onclick="printpage()" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="btntype" value="Submit" />
<input type="submit" name="btntype" value="Print" onclick="printpage()" />
```

Then in the form processing code check the value of "btntype" and do A if value = "Submit" and B if value = "Print". The onclick event for the "Print" submit button calls the printpage function and does all of its stuff before the form is submitted normally.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

This is a problem. Remove the name="submit" and it should work. Each of the form elements that have the name attribute also create a property in the form object. This element creates a property "submit" which overwrites the form's submit method.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. Clicking on the "Print" button still just displays the windows print dialog and the alert and nothing else happens. Thanks for the suggestion.